# Job search pagination is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Pagination on job search appears to be broken.

When I search for "most recent" (with no or some search and location keywords) and then visit page 2, I get the result "0 jobs". This is despite the search indicating 8 or more pages of results.

Here is a link as an example: https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=p&pg=2

Comment: Also broken in the new Jobs tab on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=p&pg=2

Comment: Looking now. (15 characters)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the report, Rowan. I've just deployed the fix for this. It should be better now.